# Direcionar saída de um programa para 2 lugares

Tags: linux, windows

Sei que no Linux ou Windows consigo redirecionar a sáida de um programa para ser salva em um arquivo em vez de ser mostrada no terminar com o comando `>`:

```
./a.out > arqSaida.txt
```

Ou ainda escrever no final do arquivo em vez de substituí-lo:

```
./a.out >> arqSaida.txt
```

Existe alguma forma de mostrar a saída do programa no terminal para eu poder acompanhar sua execução e ao mesmo tempo salvar a saída em um arquivo? Vale lembrar que só tenho o compilado do programa, portanto não posso alterá-lo!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O comando que você está procurando é o `tee`. Seu exemplo ficaria assim, com saída no terminal atual e em `arqSaida.txt` simultaneamente:

```
./a.out | tee arqSaida.txt
```

Comment: Muito obrigado!